# Property access modifiers with setters and getters

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, automatic-properties

I have the following  C# code:

```
class C
{
    public int A { get; private set; }
}
```

How is the access modifier placed before the property type and name ('public' in this example) related to the specified access modifiers for the getters and setters?

Comment: more information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that `getter` of this property is `public`, but `setter` is `private` - you can read this property outside class or assembly, but you can set it only inside the class this property is declared.

If you don't specify modifier for getter or setter then they will have modifier before property name:

```
protected int Value {get; set;}
```

It means that you can read and write this property only inside this class or classes that inherit this one - `getter` and `setter` have modifier `protected`.

You can restrict `getter` or `setter` of the property for your needs but modifier of `getter` or `setter` should be more strict than modifier before property name.

Also, you can't restrict both `getter` and `setter` because in this case the modifier before property name will not have some meaning. You can restrict only `getter` or only `setter`.